# GNU Radio installation failure

Tags: gnuradio

Can anyone help in installing "wxgui" component in gnuradio-companion using Ubuntu?

Everytime I try to install, it comes with the following error

```
"The following components were skipped either because you asked not
to build them or they didn't pass configuration checks:

**gr-wxgui**

These components will not be built."
```

I installed all the prerequisite python packages, but still I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the build-gnuradio script?

http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/InstallingGR#Using-the-build-gnuradio-script

Comment: Or [PyBOMBS](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/pybombs/wiki), which was designed to slowly replace build-gnuradio?

Answer (score 0):

pybombs was the best way for me to install gnuradio. It take long time but work fine without error : http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/pybombs/wiki/QuickStart